# CSS Attribute Selectors in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In CSS there are many attribute selectors like

```
a[href$=mp3] { // this means that if there is a <a> and it has href attribute and the href ends-with mp3 then apply my style 
   .... my style
}
```

So What if I want to do something like this in JQuery

```
$("a[href$=mp3]").click(function ()) {
    alert("An audio link is clicked !!");
});
```

But it is giving me an error/exception at first line

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Can anybody fix it or give me a work around ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is just an error of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last `)` on the first line should not be there. That's causing the syntax error.

```
$("a[href$=mp3]").click(function ()) {
//                                 ^ remove
```

Comment: Thanks !! This is a silly question ... I want to delete it but I can't !!

Answer (score 1):

You have extra braces which is causing the error due to incorrect syntax:

```
$("a[href$=mp3]").click(function () {
                                 //^------removed extra )
  alert("An audio link is clicked !!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href$=mp3]").click(function ()) { 
                                   ^------- extra closing brace
                                            that is causing the syntax error
```

supposed to be

```
$("a[href$=mp3]").click(function () {
```